# p5.sound.js audioBuffer is undefined

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I'm trying to create a simple web interface, which is displayed by a Node.js server where, when I press a "Start" button,the page starts recording audio from the device microphone, and when I press a "Stop" button, the page stops recording and saves the audio as a wav file. I'm using the [0.10.2 release](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases) of p5.sound.js to implement the recorder. I've used both p5.js and p5.sound.js as scripts at the bottom of the body of my html file:

```
<script src='./js/p5.js'>
<script src='./js/p5.sound.js'>
<script src='./js/main.js'>
```

The script files were downloaded and saved on a local folder. Here is main.js:

```
'use strict';

let mic, recorder, soundFile;

const start = document.querySelector('button#start');   
const stop = document.querySelector('button#stop');

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // initialization
    mic = new p5.AudioIn();                 // create an audio in
    mic.start();                            // enable mic

    recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();      // create a sound recorder
    recorder.setInput(mic);                 // connect the mic to the recorder

    soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();         // create an empty sound file

    // start recording
    recorder.record(soundFile);             
    console.log('Recording audio');
});

stop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    recorder.stop();                        // stop recorder, and send the result to soundFile
    console.log('Recording stopped');
    soundFile.save('test.wav');
});
```

The code is mostly based on the [example](https://p5js.org/examples/sound-record-save-audio.html) in the p5.js site. But when I run the page and click the Stop button, the console displays `TypeError: audioBuffer is undefined`. I'm not sure where the problem lies because when I checked the script files, audioBuffer seems to have been defined there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a little weird but the implementation of *p5.js* requires that you instantiate its class to make it work.

The problem lies in the `convertToWav()` helper function of *p5.sound.js* library, which is called when your try to save your soundFile, and where the audioBuffer is undefined. I still do not really know why.

I am able to save the file like this, thanks to this [p5.js issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1379):

```
new p5().save(soundFile, 'test.wav');
```

or with a global instantiation:

```
new p5();
...
saveSound(soundFile, 'test.wav');
```

Maybe not to considering to follow best coding practices is inherited from [*Processing*](https://processing.org/) culture, which is primarily designed for artists, who don't really care about *JavaScript* scope pollution.

Or maybe the doc example of `soundFile.save` is not clear enough.

See also [this Processing forum post](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/16932/can-t-save-my-soundfile-with-p5-sound) that says almost the same thing.